# Can a lightning cable plug get short circuited by a metal surface?

Tags: hardware, power, charger, lightning

I have a couple of lightning connectors on a flat surface, ready to plug into an iPhone or iPad for charging. At the same time, a Macbook or iPad is sometimes placed near that surface.

Can the body of the Macbook or iPad actually short circuit the lightning connector? (since their 4 pins are exposed), and have potential fire hazard at the adapter if it is the official Apple adapter or the popular Anker brand?

Comment: Are you assuming that the lightning cable is plugged-in to a power source at the same time?  FYI, you need to complete a circuit for electricity to travel and I'm not sure doing this will actually complete the circuit.

Comment: there is not a lot of voltage going through the lightning connector and the circuitry in the connector and iOS devices have protections built-in to their circuitry to prevent issues should a short occur. This is standard, *elementary* circuit design. In other words unless you apply outside voltage you have nothing to worry about.

Comment: @fsb yes, the lightning cable there is to charge any device, so it is plugged into an adapter

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that that can happen: when you look carefully at the lightning connector you will see that the metal body of your mac will touch the upperside of the lightning connector which is one band only and not one of the contacts that are on the sides.

Comment: I thought the 4 pins are identical the upper side and bottom side (that's why you can plug it either way), but I could be mistaken